# How to track element impressions via Google Tag Mager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How do I track via GTM if certain element have impressions? Let say I would like to know how many times this element have been seen?
`<div class="box"><div> class"text"><span>Text</span</div</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom JavaScript variable to check if an element with the `.box` class exists.

Something like:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("box")){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You can then use this in your trigger (eg. your custom variable > equals > true).

Comment: Element is loaded every page load if user is not logged in and class  .box appears only for users who has not logged in. So I guess it would be enough if I could track page views where class .box was included in DOM. User does not have to perform actions so there is no need for click event.

Comment: This should be a comment. It surely isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can track impressions with one custom HTML tag and a custom event trigger. You need to attach an event listener to a function that checks if the element is visible on the page:

```html
<script>
    var hasDeals = document.getElementsByClassName('box').length;
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    var elVisible = false;
    var eventPushed = false;
      
    if(hasDeals>0) {  
     document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {{isScrolledIntoView(element);}} );
    }
      
    function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
     if(!elVisible) {  
          var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
          var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
          var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
          elVisible = isVisible;
          return isVisible;
        } else if(!eventPushed) {
          dataLayer.push({'event': 'dealVisible'});
          eventPushed = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

From there on you just need to create the trigger and use it as you wish.
You can find more explanations about how this script works and how to edit it for other scenarios here: [Tracking Elements Impression with Google Tag Manager](https://gtm.tips/custom-gtm-trigger-html-element-impression/)